# Why ModelState.IsValid is false as condition is true?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SecurityMappingModel objModel)
{

    //edit code

    if (objModel.Id != Guid.Empty)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            mappings = (List<SecurityMappingModel>)Session["Mappings"];
            var objRemove = mappings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == objModel.Id);
            if (objRemove != null)
            {
                mappings.Remove(objRemove);
                mappings.Add(objModel);
                ViewBag.Mappings = mappings;
            }
            Session["Mappings"] = mappings;
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

inside objModel one of the field is having value 0 as it is a textfield i'm putting value into it but inside Controller oject objModel showing that field value is zero :( :( why???

Comment: I can't make sense of your question.

Comment: i'm taking everything into Session object and thenpassing it to Webgrid to all data on Webgrid...Webgrid having edit , delete buttons...when i try to edit it is going into Post Index() Action here i'm getting error as ModelState is false why ? it must be true right

Comment: when i insert data at that time ModelState is true as expected but When I try to Edit it is showing my False Why ? where i go wrong?

Comment: It is not appropriate to completely change your question. Start a new one if necessary.

Comment: ok sorry i will but can you solve my query plzzz

Comment: inside objModel one of the field is having value 0 as it is a textfield i'm putting value into it but inside Controller oject objModel showing that field value is zero :( :( why???

Comment: @ashuthinks you are trying to work on ASP.NET MVC framework without having some basic knowledge on that, i checked your previous questions too... I would tell you have a look the book "Pro ASP.NET MVC 3", would be much helpful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (yourGuid != Guid.Empty)
```

Comment: hi,
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(SecurityMappingModel objModel)
        {
            //edit code
            if (objModel.Id != Guid.Empty)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    mappings = (List<SecurityMappingModel>)Session["Mappings"];
                    var objRemove = mappings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == objModel.Id);
                    Session["Mappings"] = mappings;
Guid is there do 1st if condition passed but ModelState coming false :( why??

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this kind of error.

Maybe the solution to your problem is placing a code like this in your Home.cshtml view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```